# Сайт на разных браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, opera

В хроме ведет себя нормально, но вот в опере и firefox появляется какая то белая простыня. Не могу понять от чего. Кроссбраузерность делал.

[image: Opera]

[image: FireFox]

[image: Chrome]

Так же в Firefox почему то не работают значки из http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: у меня и хроме не работает ваш сайт , для начала уберите ваш flex полностью , я в dev tools убрал и сайт стал на 100% , так же у вас проблемы с font, далее у вас так же есть position absolute который не совместим с flex , вы уже выбирайте что вы хотите видеть - flex или block

Comment: Добавьте проблемный участок кода непосредственно в вопрос, иначе скорее всего он будет закрыт.

Comment: и вам на сайте не нужен слайдер, а нужен обычная мена изображений

Comment: Без кода невозможно воспроизвести вашу проблему. Если нужно дебажить код, всегда прикладывайте минимальный пример для воспроизведения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
.owl-carousel {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

2.

```
.main__container {
...
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

3. C FA FF не дружит, поищите решения в поиске для мозилы с font awesome.

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло, опять наступил на старые грабли. Скажите по поводу значков, есть ли у вас (если не долго искать) хорошая альтернатива?

Comment: Вот следующую ответ и мне помог, нужно скачивать шрифты, а не устанавливать их через cdnjs и прочее (http: // ... ). И подключать в стили font-awesome.css (там же в файлах при скачивании найдете).

Answer (score 1):

По поводу fontawesome и ff

1. качаем http://fontawesome.ru/ шрифт отсюда и в корень проекта закидываем папку fonts
2. Добавляем в css следующий код:`@font-face {
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   }`

Comment: Ваш вариант чем то отличается? у пользователя эти иконки не отображаются только в браузере Firefox.

Comment: Отличается тем, что изначально я не скачивал шрифты. А в этом примере скачал и по другому подключил.